# When Ltrim and Rtrim are actually needed in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, union

Help me understand SQL and string with spaces and stuff

**Using the following data as sample:**

```
with sampletable as (
select '       0123456789      ' as num --1 / 23c
union all
select '0123456789' as num  --2  / 10c
union all
select '       0123456789' as num  --3 / 17
union all
select '             0123456789' as num  --4 / 23c
union all
select '0123456789             ' as num  --5 / 23c
union all
select '0123456789 ' as num  --6 / 11c
union all
select ' 0123456789' as num  --7 / 11c
)
```

**DISTINCT** 
This is equivalent as using `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`

```
select distinct num,len(num), count(distinct num) from sampletable group by num
```

Result **4** rows [4,1,5,2]

**INNER JOIN AGAINST SELF**

```
select a.num, len(a.num) from sampletable a inner join sampletable b on a.num=b.num
```

Result **15** rows (7 + 7 = ?)

**INNER JOIN AGAINST `LTRIM(RTRIM(num))`**

```
select a.num, len(a.num) from sampletable a inner join sampletable b on a.num=ltrim(rtrim(b.num))
```

Result **21** rows // all length 10

```
select num, len(num) from sampletable
```

Result **4** rows

Comment: trailing spaces are ignored in SQL Server for comparisons and `LEN`. So `''0123456789             '` it's equal  to `'0123456789  '` or `'0123456789'`, etc

Comment: @lamak Yep, but can't figure out the when and why. So, you are saying the rule is 1 space right is equal to n+1 spaces?

Comment: ?, the `why` it's because that's the way it's designed in SQL Server. I don't understand the `when` question

Comment: Off topic, but still useful to know: `SELECT` is actually the short form of `SELECT ALL`, and  `UNION` is the short form of `UNION DISTINCT`.

Comment: If you want to know more about trailing spaces, you can [look here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10510/behavior-of-varchar-with-spaces-at-the-end). But the answer is just that that's the ANSI standard

Comment: @jarlh Thank you. Usefull to remember, indeed.

Comment: @Lamak thank you. That's actually the answer. Can you post it?

Comment: When you do a regular GROUP BY, the result is already without duplicates, so no need to do SELECT DISTINCT in that case.

Comment: @jarlh it was for the count.

Comment: Your example does `SELECT DISTINCT ... GROUP BY ...`. No need for that DISTINCT.